# PreparedStatement performance tuning

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there any way to improve performance of prepared statements? It's about many select queries. I do the queries like this way:

```
 String query = "SELECT NAME, ADDRESS " 
                + "FROM USERS "
                + "where ID = ? "
                + "group by NAME, ADDRESS";

PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);

for(long id: listIDs){
   pstmt.setLong(1, id);
   ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

   ...
}
```

The database is MySQL.

Comment: What database are you working with?

Comment: @NickHolt I update my question. The database is MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Make sure the `ID` field is indexed.
2. Combine many small queries into one, for example by using `WHERE ID IN (...)`.

For a more detailed discussion of the latter, see [Batching Select Statements in JDBC](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2).

Comment: If you're using Oracle you can create a custom type that's an array of numbers and join against - it'll perform better than a `IN` and is less prone to injection attacks (only if your id were a `VARCHAR`).

Answer (score 2):

It's the server that prepares the queries (that's why you need a connection). To improve performance of prepared statements you have to tune the DB server itself (indexes, etc...).

Another way, is writing queries that only get the results you want.

Another idea is to cache in client side the data you know you'll be using a lot, this way you won't be querying the DB for the same data again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to investigate whether your JDBC driver supports statement caching. I know oracle's JDBC driver does support.